# Делаю подгрузку элементов при скролле. Почему первые 10 элементов дублируются?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, прокрутка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Использую библиотеку **react-infinite-scroller** для подгрузки элементов при скролле.

Делаю по этой демо: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238667/infinite-scrolling-with-react-js - самый последний пример в ответе, но в моем случае в json не будет "следующей страницы", то есть подгружать элементы можно только меняя счетчик страницы на +1.

Как понять, почему дублируются первые 10 элементов?

Вот демо: https://anastasiabro.github.io/example/

Вот код:

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import People from './containers/People/People';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <People/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`People.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';

import './People.css';

let baseURL = 'https://swapi.co/api/people?page=1';
localStorage.setItem('next', 1);
let url = '';

class People extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            isLoading: false,
            hasMoreItems: true

        }
    }

    loadContent () {
        this._isMounted = true;
        let url = baseURL;
        let self = this;

        console.log(baseURL); //первая страница https://swapi.co/api/people?page=1

        console.log(url); //https://swapi.co/api/people?page=1

        if (localStorage.getItem('next') != 1) {

            url = 'https://swapi.co/api/people?page=' + localStorage.getItem('next'); //https://swapi.co/api/people?page=2
            console.log('ссылка изм', url);

        }

        fetch(url)
        .then( (response) => {
            return response.json() })   
                .then( (json) => {

                        var list = this.state.data; //на второй итерации массив из 10 элементов            
                        json.results.map(data => {
                            list.push(data);
                        });

                        console.log(json.count,  '>' , (Number(localStorage.getItem('next'))) * 10); // на второй итерации 87 > 10

                    if (json.count > (localStorage.getItem('next') * 10)) {
                        console.log(this.state.data.length, localStorage.getItem('next') * 10); //на второй итерации 10 10



                            localStorage.setItem('next', Number(localStorage.getItem('next')) + 1);
                            url = 'https://swapi.co/api/people?page=' + localStorage.getItem('next');
                            console.log(url); //на второй итерации https://swapi.co/api/people?page=2

                            self.setState({
                                data: list
                            });
                            //this.loadContent();

                        console.log('ссылка изменилась?', localStorage.getItem('next')); //2
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            hasMoreItems: false
                        });
                    }
                    console.log(this.state.data); // на второй итерации массив из 10 эл.

                })
                .catch(error => console.log('err ' + error));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadContent();
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    render () {
        const loader = <div className="loader">Загрузка...</div>;
        console.log(this.state.data);
        let items = null;

        if (this.state.data !== undefined) {
            let results = this.state.data;

            items = results.map(item => {
                return <div className="item"
                        key={item.created}
                        >{item.name}</div>
            });

            return (
                <div>
                    <InfiniteScroll
                        pageStart={0}
                        loadMore={this.loadContent.bind(this)}
                        hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems}
                        loader={loader}
                        key={this.props.id}
                        >
                            <ul className="product__list" onScroll={event => this.onScrollList(event)} transition="ease 0.5s" >{items}</ul>
                    </InfiniteScroll>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="spinner">Загрузка...</div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default People;
```

Comment: печалька какая-то :(

Comment: а что выводят все ваши `console.log`? с сервера приходят нужные данные? что в `list` на момент рендера находится? так же дубликаты?

Comment: @ThisMan
С сервера приходят нужные данные, но первая десятка два раза приходит, остальное по 1 разу. Первая ссылка два раза в консоли, то есть почему-то после первой загрузки до счетчика не доходит даже и в консоли ничего не выводится, сразу снова тот же запрос идет.

Comment: В `list` сначала 10 элементов в массиве, потом 20, потом 30 и т.д. Но после первого запроса в консоли пусто

Comment: вы это в коде хотя бы покажите комментарием, а то не понятно что и где смотреть

Comment: не знаю, насколько помогут комментарии - они в коде теперь, но могу сказать, что когда в данных вторая итерация и должны прийти новые 20, то приходят старые 10 снова, хотя линк и счетчик уже изменились

Comment: если проблема именно в ответе, то может стоит проверить серверный код?

Comment: на сервере все хорошо, если вывести все, то все ок, это у меня проблемы)

Comment: в любом случае спасибо за внимание, буду думать дальше

Comment: проверила для случая, когда в json есть след. ссылка (в точности как в исходном коде) - так вот там тоже также дубликат)) изначально в коде ошибка есть

Comment: А почему изпользуете `localStorage` вместо `this.state`. Вроде как Реакт, вроде Best Practice?

Comment: потому что не сразу обновляется setstate, даже если вторым аргументом коллбек ставила, все равно еще больше путаюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';

// import './People.css';

const BASE_URL = 'https://swapi.co/api/people';

class People extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      paginationIndex: 1,
      data: [],
      isLoading: false,
      hasMoreItems: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  loadContent() {
    const { paginationIndex, data } = this.state;
    this._isMounted = true;

    fetch(`${BASE_URL}?page=${paginationIndex}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          data: [...data, ...json.results],
          paginationIndex: paginationIndex + 1,
          hasMoreItems: json.count >= paginationIndex * 10
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('err ' + error));
  }

  render () {
    const loader = <div className="loader">Загрузка...</div>;
    console.log(this.state.data);
    let items = null;

    if (this.state.data !== undefined) {
      let results = this.state.data;

      items = results.map(item => {
        return <div className="item"
                key={item.created + Math.random().toString().slice(-5)}
                >{item.name}</div>
      });

      return (
        <div>
          <InfiniteScroll
            pageStart={0}
            loadMore={this.loadContent.bind(this)}
            hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems}
            loader={loader}
            key={this.props.id}
            >
              <ul
                className="product__list"
                transition="ease 0.5s"
              >
                {items}
              </ul>
          </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="spinner">Загрузка...</div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default People;
```

Рефакторнул с использованием `state` вместо `localStorage`. Работает.

Если расссматривать в чем же именно дело, то причина в том что `localStorage` не успевает обновится, и ре-рендер происходит раньше повторяя запрос еще со старыми данными

Comment: Спасибо вам за интерес к вопросу) Да, это действительно работает. И ключи вы добавили. Но я не совсем понимаю, что же повлияло в итоге - спред оператор? Только один момент - решение выводит 80 элементов, когда их 87 должно быть.

Comment: Повлияло то что я описал выше:
"причина в том что localStorage не успевает обновится, и ре-рендер происходит раньше повторяя запрос еще со старыми данными"

При использовании state мы гарантировано получаем новое значение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Странно, начинала со стейтами, но у меня просто в loadContent было условие для выбора url - базовый или после обновления счетчика - может, поэтому не работало. Интересно)

Comment: аааа, только что увидел что там передается метод, сейчас чуть еще изменб код

Comment: Изменил код, теперь всё будет работать правильно и будет 87 единиц.
Я упустил из виду то что `this.loadContent` вызывается в двух местах, и из-за этого есть путаница, убрал лишнее

Comment: Это очень здорово! Спасибо вам большое, вы невероятно мне помогли. Все работает!